# Hierarchical data to be arranged

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Hierarchical data is to be arranged.
Imagine that df is given.  (Here i generate df with some fake data )

```
df1 <-data.frame("Col1" = rep("a",8), "Col2"= c(rep("M",3),rep("N",2), rep("O", 2), rep("P",1)), "Col3" = LETTERS[1:8])
df2 <-data.frame("Col1" = rep("b",13), "Col2"= c(rep("p",4),rep("q",5),rep("r",3),rep("s",1)), "Col3" = LETTERS[1:13])
df <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

For each element of Col1, we have to get a collection in sorted way

Finally, what i look for is a list of lists :
  list a : (1,2,2,3)
  list b : (1,3,4,5)

Comment: Remove the python tag please, this is a question pertaining to R

Comment: Show your desired output.  list a : (1,2,2,3) list b : (1,3,4,5) does not make sense given the structure of df.

Comment: Corresponding to "a" : total 8 elements in Col3 . When you see Col2, you will see 3 M, 2 N, 2 O, 1 P .  Sorted way : (1,2,2,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ll <- split(df, df$Col1)
lapply(ll, function(dat){
    v <- Filter(function(v) !is.na(v), with(dat, tapply(Col1, Col2, length)))
    v[order(v)]
})
```